# Absolute PATH in parse_yaml_file is not working but everything else is perfect

Tags: php, database, file, path, yaml

I'm reading an yaml file inside a class, this file contains information about my database so I can connect to it. Trying to open inside the class doesn't work, trying to open in the global scope works.  Relative PATHS doesn't work either. I'm instantiating this class inside another file **register-ajax.php**, when I instantiate It I get the error: **No such file or directory**.
Below is the code and the folder structure of my project.

```
<?php
//This works
//var_dump(yaml_parse_file("/var/www/omeglall/yaml/connection.yaml");

class MySQL
{
    private $HOST;
    private $PASSWORD;
    private $USER;
    private $DATABASE;
    private $con;
//PATH IS 200% CORRECT
    const CONNECTION_PATH="/var/www/omeglall/yaml/connection.yaml";
    static private $connection_YAML;
    
    public  function __construct()
    {

        try
        {
            $this->load_config();
            mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

            $this->con=new mysqli($this->HOST,$this->USER,$this->PASSWORD,$this->DATABASE);
            if($this->con->connect_error)
            {
                throw new Exception("Connection failed:". $this->con->connect_error);
            }
            $this->con->set_charset("utf8mb4");
            
            
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $error=$e->getMessage();
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    
    public function getCon()
    {
        return $this->con;
    }
    private function load_config()
    {
        
        if(empty(self::$connection_YAML)){
//THIS DOESN'T WORK!
            self::$connection_YAML=yaml_parse_file(self::CONNECTION_PATH);

        }
        
      
        $file=self::$connection_YAML;
        $this->HOST=$file["host"];
        $this->USER=$file["user"];
        $this->PASSWORD=$file["password"];
        $this->DATABASE=$file["database"];

    }

}

?>
```

[Folder Structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmYFC.png)

Comment: You can remove `if($this->con->connect_error)`. It's a dead code.

Comment: You really should remove try-catch. It doesn't do anything useful and if you run this code in production server it will leak sensitive DB credentials to the users.

Comment: Although I absolutely believe that you believe that the path is correct, the error message says differently. Maybe something wasn't saved when you ran it? Absolute should work regardless of global/function/class, relative is where vague/surprising things can happen. You can add some additional sanity guards before the YAML stuff such as `is_file` and `is_readable`, just to get different error messages.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply, but I already fixed the problem :)

Comment: Also Dharman I removed the Try catch as you said, thank you

Comment: if($this->con->connect_error) condition should be removed as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the error was coming from Mysql and not from the function yaml_parse_file, for some reason mysql stops running out of nowhere and then I have to start it again

Comment: Although I'm very happy that you were able to resolve your issue, and that you posted something for us for closure, because your problem and resolution were completely unrelated to the question asked my recommendation would be to delete the original question. Future readers might possibly have a similar question and I don't think following this page will help them in any way.